# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{-2^n}\cos{(2^n)-2^{-3(2^n)}\cos{(3(2^n))}}}{2^{2^{n+2}}-2^{1-2^{n+1}}\cos{(2^{n+1})}+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I want to find the value of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{-2^n}\cos{(2^n)-2^{-3\cdot2^n}\cos{(3\cdot2^n)}}}{2^{2^{n+2}}-2^{1-2^{n+1}}\cos{(2^{n+1})}+2}$$

We have an identity $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^m\dfrac{2^ny^{2^n}}{x^{2^n}+y^{2^n}}=\dfrac{y}{x-y}-\dfrac{2^{m+1}y^{2^{m+1}}}{x^{2^{m+1}}-y^{2^{m+1}}}$

I try to solve it by replace $y=e^{i}$ or $x=e^i$ or take derivative both sides.

However, It doesn't work.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: for $n=10$ we get $$- 0.0004618733229471734029937842107349159995846365360909729508977099845455741736836539459050316598547623579$$